# Window function in Spark Dstream results in long pending tasks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, windowing

We are trying to implement the Window function in spark. Spark is receiving data through Kafka (having 5 partitions) and we are using Spark Java DStream for processing. Once a comma separated data from kafka is mapped to a object in Spark, we then create a window of 20 sec, which is sliding at 1 sec. On this Java DStream  we count and print the output (actually we want to do more processing but for simplicity only count is applied). Everything works fine till a spike occurs in the processing time, which takes around 40 sec for processing one task and post this, we get a long queue.
Cluster Details:
    - 3 node cluster
    - each having 45 cores (total 135 Cores)
    - each having 256 GB RAM 
Setup Tested:
  Setup 1:-
    - 5 Kafka partitions
    - 20 Sec Window, sliding at 1 Sec
    - 9 Executors per Node (Total 27 Executors)
    - Allocating 10 GB to each Executor
  Setup 2:-
    - 5 Kafka partitions
    - 20 Sec Window, sliding at 1 Sec
    - **45** Executors per Node (Total 135 Executors)
    - Allocating **1** GB to each Executor
  Setup 3:-
    - 5 Kafka partitions
    - 20 Sec Window, sliding at 1 Sec
    - **15** Executors per Node (Total 45 Executors)
    - Allocating **6** GB to each Executor
  Setup 4:-
    - 5 Kafka partitions
    - **120** Sec Window, sliding at 1 Sec
    - 9 Executors per Node (Total 27 Executors)
    - Allocating 10 GB to each Executor
  Setup 5:- (This is our Actual Scenario)
    - **27** Kafka partitions
    - **120** Sec Window, sliding at 1 Sec
    - 9 Executors per Node (Total 27 Executors)
    - Allocating 10 GB to each Executor

In All setups, at some point the processing takes too much of time (close to 40 sec in majority of processing issues).
It will be great if some one has a solution to it or any parameter change suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable backpressure if you don't want queue to build up. This is done by setting the spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled to true and its available since spark 1.5
Other than that, its important to understand at what rate is the data produced by producers and whether you have sufficient resource to process data at that rate. Spark-UI will give you some insights into this. 
There are other factors to consider that would impact the performance such as whether you are using a receiver-based approach or kafka-direct, with or without replication, with or without checkpointing, etc.

Comment: The data producing rate is 10k/sec. messages from kafka.

Comment: Are you using receiver-based approach. If you are then are you parallelising receivers. Checkpointing slows things down considerably so if you can avoid it, I'd recommend that. Spark-UI will give you some insights about bottlenecks. spark-lint is another tool that can show you cluster utilization.

Comment: We are using `.createDirectStream` approach. In this, the kafka partitions are one-to-one mapped to spark consumers.

Comment: In that case you can scale up by increasing the number of partitions for your kafka topic(s) which you seem to be doing. From the info you have given it is hard to pin point the actual cause but it doesn't seem to be a scalability issue. What is your task doing that gets stuck for 40 secs. Does spark-UI give any useful insight into this?